# Android Studio and Google Play Games

Tags: java, android

So I have a sign in button and I assigned it an ID then referenced that ID in code.. now I have been following the Android Documentation and it's telling me to use BaseGameActivity but I don't understand how to get BaseGameUtils (library) to get into the project I am working on so I can use BaseGameActivity.. I am using this tutorial

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart

Thanks!

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio this shouldn't be too hard.  First, download the [android-basic-samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) repository from Github where the `BaseGameUtils` module is contained.  Open the `BasicSample` project in Android Studio by importing the project through gradle.

Then in your other project, select **Import Module** from the Android Studio menu and import the `BaseGameUtils` module from the `BasicSamples` project you downloaded.  This should copy BaseGameUtils into your project and you should be good to go.

Also please note that `BaseGameActivity` is no longer the recommended method for getting starting with Google Play Games Services.  Although it should still work at the moment, it will no longer be updated.